# How to send a graphQl query to third party api

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

I have a endpoint which I am hitting to get data..The endpoint is

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}
```

The response it sends is below

```
{
  coord: { lon: 73.2145, lat: 34.1469 },
  weather: [
  { id: 801, main: 'Clouds', description: 'few clouds', icon: '02n' }
 ],
 base: 'stations',
 main: {
 temp: 277.91,
 feels_like: 277.91,
 temp_min: 277.91,
 temp_max: 277.91,
 pressure: 1011,
 humidity: 85,
 sea_level: 1011,
 grnd_level: 871
  },
 visibility: 10000,
 wind: { speed: 0.33, deg: 168, gust: 0.44 },
 clouds: { all: 20 },
 dt: 1643912333,
sys: {
type: 2,
id: 2007435,
country: 'PK',
sunrise: 1643853796,
sunset: 1643891911
},
 timezone: 18000,
 id: 1185056,
```

}

If I am to send a graphQL query to just get the main and wind.How would It be done I am using nestJs a nodeJs framework.

Answer (score 0):

Return the whole response of the API from the resolver and query it from the frontend

```
query {
 fetchWeather {
   main
   wind
 }
}
```

If you are Using AWS, you can use app sync and its response mapping template.